# Explanation for lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, lambda

```
public static void GetUserAccessToken(string email, string password,string deviceToken,
        Action onCompletion, Action<RestError> onError)
    {
        WebRequestBuilder builder = new WebRequestBuilder()
            .Url(GetApiUrl(Urls.USER_ACCESS_TOKEN))
            .Verb(Verbs.POST)
            .ContentType(ContentTypes.FORM)
            .FormData(Attributes.CLIENT_ID, Config.Api.PasswordGrantClientId)
            .FormData(Attributes.CLIENT_SECRET, Config.Api.PasswordGrantClientSecret)
            .FormData(Attributes.EMAIL_ID, email)
            .FormData(Attributes.PASSWORD, password)
            .FormData(Attributes.DEVICE_TOKEN, deviceToken)
            .FormData(Attributes.SCOPE, "*");

        AddClientAuthHeader(ref builder);

        _instance._restUtil.Send(builder, handler =>
        {
            var response = DataConverter.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseFormat<UserToken>>(handler.text);
            UserAccessToken = response.Data.AccessToken;
            UserRefreshToken = response.Data.RefreshToken;
            onCompletion?.Invoke();
        }, restError =>
```

I cant understnad this line:
`_instance._restUtil.Send(builder, handler => { var response = DataConverter.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseFormat<UserToken>>(handler.text);`
and specifically from where and how its going to get the value for `handler.text` since i cannot see where it is defined or passed as a parameter

Comment: `handler => { ... }` is a lambda that will receive `handler` as its only parameter when it's called. If you know about lambdas in general, as it would seem, that should not create any confusion?

Comment: The lambda-body is similar to an event-handler. So the `handler`-variable gets set when that event is raised within `Send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about lambda expressions as little methods, the lambda that you referenced would be something like this:

```cs
void Foo (Handler handler) // i am assuming that handler is of type Handler here
{
    // do whatever you want
}
```

there the 'handler' variable is passed to the lambda as parameter just like in the method above, the text field inside handler, is just a normal instance field provided by the **supposed** Handler type.

Than the implementation of the `Send` method is responsible to pass a *Handler* as argument to the lambda invocation.

Comment: The definition for Send` is this: 
``public int Send(WebRequestBuilder builder,
            Action<DownloadHandler> onCompletion, Action<RestCallError> onError)
        {
            _callQueue.Enqueue(new Call()
            {
                Builder = builder,
                OnCompletion = onCompletion,
                OnError = onError
            });

            return _callCounter++;
        }`` 
i cannot see how it is going to find an instance of `DownloadHandler` to use when `GetUserAccessToken` is called

Comment: That is something handled by the `Call` class, since the method is only calling the constructor (which accepts an Action<DownloadHandler> as property intializer) on a method invocation, and then it returns something.